# How to get variables of clicked li(Javascript,Materialize)?

Tags: javascript, html-lists

I have 3 li's and want to get all variables of the clicked li (name,distance,Ort,PLZ).
I'm new in Javascript and I'm thankfull for every help.

```
  const li = `
  <li id= "${doc_id}">
    <div class="collapsible-header grey lighten-4 right-align"> ${name} ${distance}km from you (${Ort},${PLZ}) </div>
    <div class="collapsible-body white"><span>hey</span>
  </li>
  <li id= "${doc_id}">
    <div class="collapsible-header grey lighten-4 right-align"> ${name} ${distance}km from you (${Ort},${PLZ}) </div>
    <div class="collapsible-body white"><span>wassup</span>
  </li>
  <li id= "${doc_id}">
    <div class="collapsible-header grey lighten-4 right-align"> ${name} ${distance}km from you (${Ort},${PLZ}) </div>
    <div class="collapsible-body white"><span>lol</span>
  </li>
`;
html += li;
```

```
console.log(name,distance,Ort,PLZ)
//expectation
```

Comment: You need to write an event listener. It can use `this` to get the `li` that was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the data you want in the loop as you create the LI tags, you can insert that information as data-attributes that make it easy to retrieve when the user clicks. More explanations in comments in the below testable snippet code.

```js
// dummy data
let doc_id = 12,name = "McDonalds",distance = 123,Ort = 1,PLZ = 2

// in the div tag below, notice how I added data-attributes for distance and name
const li = `
  <li id="${doc_id}">
    <div data-name="${name}" data-distance="${distance}" class="collapsible-header grey lighten-4 right-align"> ${name} ${distance}km from you (${Ort},${PLZ}) </div>
    <div class="collapsible-body white"><span>hey</span>
  </li>
`;

// wait until the page is loaded before adding listners
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  document.querySelector('ul').innerHTML = li; // set up our dummy data for the example

  // listen to the click on the div
  document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    // check if we have clicked on one of our div tags
    if (e.target.dataset.distance !== '') {
      // we can access those data attributes with e.target.dataset.ITEM
      // the id is on the LI tag, so we grab that from the parentNode property
      console.log(`Clicked on! id: ${e.target.parentNode.id}, name: ${e.target.dataset.name}, distance: ${e.target.dataset.distance} `);
    }
  })

})
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```